# How to keep value using .php?name=$_REQUEST['name'] in link when using a header to the same page?

Tags: php, sql

I was doing gallery using SQL and PHP and encountered a problem. I have 3 .php files and on each one I need to get different kind of information from the same SQL database according to what I have chosen on the previous page.

I have done that by using

```
<a href='page3.php?name=$row[name]'>
```

thing in links and it works well when you link it to another page. But now I need to use a header to the same page and it seems to lose the information after that.

Does anyone know how to keep this information while using header to the same page? Or what would be the best different way to do it?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "header to the same page" means? Are you adding headers to the linked page, or are you changing pages using `header("location: ...")`?

Comment: What do you mean by "loose the information"?

Comment: So you're showing us the code that *is* working but not the code the question is actually about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
<a href='page3.php?name=<?php echo $row['name']; ?>'>
```

Get the data from page3.php using:

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
```